# Trying to create a Virtual Environment but I keep getting "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: python, virtualenv

I type in `virtualenv -p $(which python3.8) VirtualEnvironmentName`, but I get :

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.

I included `$(which python3.8)` so that I would have a virtual environment with Python 3.8. I want to use virtualenv to create my virtual environments for Python, but I always get the same error.

I just need to know how to use virtualenv to make a virtual environment without getting this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [This](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) code tutorial has a good example about 3/4 down the document.

Comment: Can you include the full stacktrace? How did you install python 3.8? What OS are you using?

Comment: Does `python3.8` work? Does `virtualenv VirtualEnvironmentName` work? Does `virtualenv -p python3.8 VirtualEnvironmentName` work?

Comment: python3.8 works. However, when I use virtualenv VirtualEnvironmentName, it says "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory." Also, when I use virtualenv -p python3.8 VirtualEnvironmentName, it also says "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory."